# SSRS Chart Data Drill Through only returning 1 result

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, charts

I have a Main Report with Bar and Pie Charts on it from one data source. These charts count data using an individual marker to each row, and each chart has an individual dataset with filters applied within the query.

I also have a secondary report, which I want to use to show the rows selected from within the chart. I have set this up with a multi-value parameter and no available or default results, and a filter with the 'IN' clause.

I have set up the Series properties of each chart to 'Go to Report' and pass the marker number into the multi-value parameter.

This doesn't work, and only shows me 1 row from the data region I select. How do I get it to show all the rows within the data region?

The Marker is an Integer if this helps.

If you need anymore clarification, please let me know.

Many Thanks

Update: The query for one bar chart data is as follows:

```
    SELECT LEARNERS.Firstname, LEARNERS.Surname, LEARNERS.DOB, LEARNERS.Gender, LEARNERS.Disability, LEARNERS.NewEthnic, L_QUALS.Qual_Ref, QUALIFICATIONS_1.QualLevel, QUALIFICATIONS_1.Title, L_QUALS.DateStarted, L_QUALS.DateFinished, L_QUALS.CompletionStatus, L_QUALS.Completeness, L_QUALS.DatePlannedEnd, L_QUALS.Delivery_ID, ORGANISATIONS.Name, L_QUALS.Learner_ID, SC_Ethnic.Description AS EthnicityDesc, LEARNERS.PriorAttainLevel, SC_PriorAttain.Description AS PriorDesc, QUALIFICATIONS_1.ALIBand, LEARNERS.ContractNumber, L_QUALS.FundingStream, L_QUALS.DeliveryMethod, L_QUALS.ProgrammeType, LEARNERS.DestinationCode, SC_Dest.Description, L_QUALS.CreditsAchieved, QUALIFICATIONS.ALIBand AS FwkALIBand, L_QUALS.AimType, L_QUALS.Qual_ID

    FROM L_QUALS INNER JOIN
LEARNERS ON L_QUALS.Learner_ID = LEARNERS.Learner_ID INNER JOIN
SC_Dest ON LEARNERS.DestinationCode = SC_Dest.Key_Ref AND LEARNERS.LearnerType = SC_Dest.LearnerType LEFT OUTER JOIN
QUALIFICATIONS ON L_QUALS.Sector = QUALIFICATIONS.Sector LEFT OUTER JOIN
ORGANISATIONS ON L_QUALS.Delivery_ID = ORGANISATIONS.Org_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
QUALIFICATIONS AS QUALIFICATIONS_1 ON L_QUALS.Qual_Ref = QUALIFICATIONS_1.Qual_Ref FULL OUTER JOIN
SC_PriorAttain ON LEARNERS.PriorAttainLevel = SC_PriorAttain.Key_Ref AND LEARNERS.LearnerType = SC_PriorAttain.LearnerType FULL OUTER JOIN
SC_Ethnic ON LEARNERS.NewEthnic = SC_Ethnic.Key_Ref AND LEARNERS.LearnerType = SC_Ethnic.LearnerType

    WHERE (L_QUALS.DatePlannedEnd > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND (L_QUALS.DatePlannedEnd <= @prmDateFrom) AND (L_QUALS.DatePlannedEnd < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-08-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (L_QUALS.Qual_Ref <> 'ZESF0001') AND (L_QUALS.AimType = '1' OR L_QUALS.AimType = '4')

    ORDER BY L_QUALS.Learner_ID
```

And the bar chart is: Data - (Count(QualID) and Category = TimelyAchiever which is a calculated field as follows:

```
     =IIF(
(Fields!Completeness.Value = 1) AND
(Fields!DateFinished.Value <= Parameters!prmDateFrom.Value) AND
(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!DateFinished.Value,Fields!DatePlannedEnd.Value) < 91)
,"Achiever",(
IIF((Fields!Completeness.Value = 2) OR (IsNothing(Fields!Completeness.Value)) AND
(Fields!DateFinished.Value <= Parameters!prmDateFrom.Value) AND
(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!DateFinished.Value,Fields!DatePlannedEnd.Value) < 91)
,"Continuing","No/Untimely Achievement")))
```

Apologies for starting this reply in comments, new to site. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you are passing in for the variables to the subreport? Also, can you post the query in your dataset that uses the parameter you are passing?

Comment: Also, please stop using pie charts, or at least be aware that you are most likely being ineffective at communicating information to your users. [Pie charts are bad](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Pie-Charts-Are-Bad/)  - [why you should avoid pie charts](http://www.verstaresearch.com/blog/why-you-should-avoid-pie-charts/) - [Avoid pie charts](http://mouly.me/2012/01/avoid-pie-charts/) - [pie charts are the worst](http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6) - [problems with pie charts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8974/problems-with-pie-charts)

Comment: Hi mmarie.We use pie charts as it shows comparison between to groups over varying sizes effectively (or so I've been told by management who requested it). I'll use one bar chart as an example.

Comment: The Query for the data is as follows: